# Include a module to define dynamic class method

Tags: ruby, class, module

I'm playing around with Ruby and I have written the following code:

```
module IdAndNameRedefine
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def use_id_and_name_from_module(use_attribute)
      class_eval <<CODE
        def id_and_name
          "\#{id}-\#{#{use_attribute}.downcase}"
        end
CODE
    end
  end
end


class Model
  include IdAndNameRedefine

  attr_reader :id, :name1, :name2

  def initialize(id, name1, name2)
    @id = id
    @name1 = name1
    @name2 = name2
  end

  def id_and_name
    "#{id}-#{name1}"
  end

  use_id_and_name_from_module :name2
end

model = Model.new(1, "TesT", "Test number TWO")
puts model.id_and_name
```

When I'm trying to do here is to override the class method `id_and_name` in class Model with a method dynamicly inserted by the `IdAndNameRedefine`-module. When that module is included, it creates a "static" method (really, a class method of the Model.class as I understands it) and when `use_id_and_name_from_module` is called, it creates a class method in Model which redefines the `id_and_name` to use whatever attribute of Model asked for.

**My question is..**
Are there any better way of doing this, or is this the "correct" way of doing it? I'm not really sure if I like the class_eval with takes a string where I need to escape values etc. to make this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to pass a string to `class_eval`. It can take a block instead. In fact, I can't think of a single occasion where I've had to pass a string to `class_eval`. So we can rewrite the ClassMethods module like so:

```
module ClassMethods
  def use_id_and_name_from_module(use_attribute)
    class_eval do 
      define_method(:id_and_name) {"#{id}-#{send(use_attribute).downcase}"}
    end
  end
end
```

But in this particular case, we're just telling `self` to `class_eval`, meaning we're already in that class's context. So it can actually be shortened to:

```
module ClassMethods
  def use_id_and_name_from_module(use_attribute)
    define_method(:id_and_name) {"#{id}-#{send(use_attribute).downcase}"}
  end
end
```

(I just wanted to show how `class_eval` really works, since you seemed most interested in that part.)

Comment: Thanks! I thought it looked kinda stupid, but I couldn't figure out a better way of doing it. I do believe that I tried define_method too, but that point I had the `use_id_and_name_from_module`-call in the top of the class definition, thus it didn't work (gets overwritten by the declaration in later in class I guess).

Just out of curiosity; Is there any way of placing the `use_id_and_name_from_module` in the top of the class and make sure it can't be overridden in later declarations?

Comment: You could override method_added and re-add your version whenever somebody tries to replace it. Seems a bit convoluted, though. Better just not to redefine the method in the first place.